# Finding text in html with seluim and bs4

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm trying very hard to make a webscraping bot to retrieve my grades every hour. I have already coded the part where it logs in to the website but I can't figure out how to extract just the grade with bs4 and instead end up getting most of the page.

```
# Importing all modules
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Onening myHIES through webdriver
driver=webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://hies.myschoolapp.com/app#login")
time.sleep(2.5)

# Logging in to myHIES then going on algebra grade page
driver.find_element(By.ID, "Username").send_keys("myemail")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "nextBtn").click()
time.sleep(4)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "i0118").send_keys("mypassword")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "idSIButton9").click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "idSIButton9").click()
print("*Breaths Lightly* WERE IN BABY!")
time.sleep(3.0)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#showHideGrade > div > label > span").click()
time.sleep(1.3)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="coursesContainer"]/div[1]/div[4]/a[1]').click()
print("handing off to bs4")
# Handing off manipulated page to bs4
page_source = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'lxml')
print("handed off to bs4")
for tag in soup.find_all():
    print(tag.text)
print("should have printed tag text")
```

And the this is the html of where I am attempting to extract from

```
<div class="col-md-2">        <div class="text-align-center">            <h1>                69.00<span class="lead">%</span>            </h1>            <h6>marking period</h6>        </div>                    <div class="text-align-center">                <h1>69.00<span class="lead">%</span></h1>                <h6>year</h6>            </div>            </div>
```

The code I'm trying to use to extract (again)

```
<div class="col-md-2">        <div class="text-align-center">            <h1>                69.00<span class="lead">%</span>            </h1>            <h6>marking period</h6>        </div>                    <div class="text-align-center">                <h1>69.00<span class="lead">%</span></h1>                <h6>year</h6>            </div>            </div>
```

Comment: have you tired using a browser and getting the xpath of the grades?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If provided html section is part of your soup you could try this:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

mystr_1 = '<div class="col-md-2">        <div class="text-align-center">            <h1>                69.00<span class="lead">%</span>            </h1>            <h6>marking period</h6>        </div>                    <div class="text-align-center">                <h1>69.00<span class="lead">%</span></h1>                <h6>year</h6>            </div>            </div>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(mystr_1, features='lxml')

main_div = soup.find('div', {'class': 'col-md-2'})
data_tags = main_div.find_all('h1')
data_notes = main_div.find_all('h6')

out_dct = {}
for i in range(2):
    grades = data_tags[i].text.replace(' ', '').replace('\t', '').split('\n')
    notes = data_notes[i].text.replace('\t', '').split('\n')
    out_dct['grade_' + str(i)] = grades
    out_dct['grade_' + str(i)].append(notes[0])
    
print(out_dct)

'''    R e s u l t :
{'grade_0': ['69.00%', 'marking period'], 'grade_1': ['69.00%', 'year']}
'''
```

**EDITED ANSWER**   (after new html content)
I've created a file bb1.html to store the data you sent me.
The structure of the html is quite different than in your initial post. Tryed to collect the grades and some other data connected to grades. Here is the code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('bb1.html') as f:
    mystr_1 = f.read()
    
soup = BeautifulSoup(mystr_1, features='lxml')

divs = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'col-md-2'})

lst = []
i = 0
for div in divs:
    data_tags = div.find_all('h3', {'class': 'showGrade'})
    data_notes = div.find('a', {'class': 'btn btn-default'})

    if len(data_tags) > 0:
        out_dct = {}
        grade = data_tags[0].text.replace(' ', '')
        if grade[:2] != '--':
            out_dct['grade_' + str(i+1)] = grade
            out_dct['tag_a_data-analysis'] = data_notes['data-analysis']

            grade_class = soup.find_all('a', {'href': '#academicclass/' + data_notes['data-analysis'] + '/undefined/bulletinboard'})

            if len(grade_class) > 0:
                clss = grade_class[0].find('h3').text
                out_dct['academic_class'] = clss
            i += 1
            lst.append(out_dct)
            dct = {}
print(lst)
```

.... and the result ...

```py
'''     R e s u l t i n g   l i s t    (lst):
[
    {'grade_1': '69.00%', 'tag_a_data-analysis': '113087042', 'academic_class': 'Algebra I - 8th Grade - 3 (D)'}, 
    {'grade_2': '58.33%', 'tag_a_data-analysis': '113087763', 'academic_class': 'Computer Science 8 - 1 (E)'}, 
    {'grade_3': '82.40%', 'tag_a_data-analysis': '113086978', 'academic_class': 'English 8/Boys - 3 (G)'}, 
    {'grade_4': '50.77%', 'tag_a_data-analysis': '113087637', 'academic_class': 'Leadership Seminar 8 - 1 (Q1B)'}
]
'''
```

I do hope that it could be helpfull. Regards...

Comment: Did not work it returned "File '''
c:\Users\jru21\Downloads\Project\myhies", line 43, in <module>
    grades = data_tags[i].text.replace(' ', '').replace('\t', '').split('\n')
IndexError: list index out of range
'''

Comment: I used the section of the html that you posted in the question. That string was used like the bs4 soup and it works. I don't know  how your soup really looks like. If you could provide the complete soup that you are working with maybe I could take another look.  Sorry, I'd like to help, but there is obviously something else within the soup that the code ran into instead of this string in the question...Regards...

Comment: There could be some other differently strutured divs of the same class (col-md-2), In that case you should locate the right one.

Comment: I have just posted the complete code so you can  test it ....

Comment: https://paste-bin.xyz/paste.php?download&id=77265&password=$2y$10$7oi7ZC/Tv0CV6DbfyBXmpOq0nhccg0wwbSMmpyev9/hxSXdS3XuWuthe password is 9561

Comment: YES!!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH! YOU AN ABSULTE GENUIS!

Comment: @Jack Underwood : You are welcome, any time... Glad to know it was helpfull. Regards...

Answer (score 0):

You will need to mention specifically which tag you need to find, otherwise, find_all would return all tags. In your case, since the text you are looking for is in h1 tag, you will need to pass this to find_all.

```
for tag in soup.find_all("h1"):
print(tag.text)
```

If you wish to read more on find_all, please see this [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#calling-a-tag-is-like-calling-find-all).

Comment: This code would fail with IndentationError: expected an indented block. And affter correction it returns unformated string with a lot of space characters and some not needed '\n'-s meaning it should be corrected before further use. And there are no notes from tags 'h6' describing the grades.

Comment: this code did not work